# RabbitMQ: Install client library erlang

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I tried to install rabbitMQ at my Archlinux machine.

I managed to install the server and run it as a service.

How can I install rabbitMQ Erlang client library?

The [www.rabbitmq.com](http://www.rabbitmq.com) has only link to the library to download

- [amqp_client-2.8.2.ez](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-erlang-client/v2.8.2/amqp_client-2.8.2.ez)
- [rabbit_common-2.8.2.ez](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-erlang-client/v2.8.2/rabbit_common-2.8.2.ez)

Any idea where to put this files?

From RabbitMQ documentation:

```
To gain access to these records, you need to include
the amqp_client.hrl in every module that uses the Erlang client:
-include("amqp_client.hrl").
```

Where should this file be located?

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/code.html

.ez is a regular ZIP file

Comment: So if I put these files in ./ebin folder and start erlang as erl -pa ./ebin everything should be OK?

Comment: ez files is a experimental feature... For now, I just recommend you to rename `amqp_client-2.8.2.ez` to `amqp_client-2.8.2.zip`, extract it to your app's `deps/` folder (so, there is `deps/amqp_client/{ebin,include}` folders) and run erl as usual `erl -pa ebin -pa deps/*/ebin`

Answer (score 1):

I read your question again and I misread it the first time.  There is a [great mini walkthrough](http://cartesianfaith.wordpress.com/2011/01/24/rabbitmq-client-examples-using-rebar/) on how to setup a new project with the Erlang RabbitMQ libraries with Rebar.  [Rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar) is a great build tool for Erlang projects.

---

Generally speaking, the hrl file should be in the same directory as the erlang file that needs it.  Alternatively, you can setup a directory hierarchy with your source in one directory and the hrl files in another, and reference the hrl file with a relative path.  For example, if you had the directory structure below, as you might with a rebar based project:

```
project
|
|----ebin
|    compiled_file.beam
|
|----src
|    srouce_file.erl
|
|----include
     include_file.hrl
```

and you wanted to include include_file.hrl in source_file.erl, would write at the top of source_file.erl:

```
-include("../include/include_file.hrl").
```